# Find at least one distribution with given parameters

Tags: numerics, probability-or-statistics, distributions

There is a continuous probability distribution that I have only limited information about. I know that its PDF is a smooth unimodal function with exactly $2$ inflection points; I also know numeric values of its $3$ quartiles, mode, mean, variance, skewness and kurtosis. Can *Mathematica* generate at least one distribution that satisfy all these criteria? It is not necessarily one of well-known named distributions like `NormalDistribution` or `ChiSquareDistribution`.

Comment: Do you have data drawn from this distribution? How would you like the distribution to be defined? As a combination of known one? Do you have an algorithmic approach in mind? If so, then please include it and I am sure somebody could help you implement it. Otherwise, at this preliminary stage the question seems more appropriate for [CrossValidated](https://statistics.stackexchange.com) than for this forum.

Comment: No, I do not have a data sample, I only have several numbers that describe the distribution; I do not have control over a process that was used to find them. I would like to get the result as some formula for PDF with coefficients selected to fit the given parameters, or an interpolating function, or some other form suitable for numeric computations. I do not have a good algorithm so far, but I wonder if _Mathematica_ capabilities for formula search and curve fitting can be used for my purposes; something similar to `SmoothKernelDistribution`, `FindDistribution`, `FindFit`, `FindFormula`, etc.

Comment: OK. You could add these details, as well as those numerical values you do have, explicitly in the question.

Comment: Here I go complaining again:  When you need a brain surgeon, you consult a brain surgeon.  You physics and engineering types certainly know a lot of math and statistics (much more than I know about physics) but you should assume that maybe this has been done before (or at least many of the issues have been thoroughly discussed).  For example, see https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/141652/constructing-a-continuous-distribution-to-match-m-moments.

Comment: @JimB Yes, that's precisely why I thought this would be more appropriate for CrossValidated...

Comment: @JimB Thank you for the reference. I missed it when I was looking for an existing answer. The reason I asked my question here was that I knew _Mathematica_ had function to construct an approximation to a distribution from a sample, so I hoped maybe there was an existing feature to do the same based on summary statistics.

Comment: Actually, my first attempt was to generate random data with a distribution that was continuously adjusted trying to better fit the sample to known summary statistics, and then apply `SmoothKernelDistribution` to the sample to find a distribution. But convergence was quite slow and the resulting PDF shape was not unimodal.

Comment: Something simple is to fit a mixture of two normals and equate the first 4 moments.  If the other summary statistics match up, then you're done.  But that's probably a bit of wishful thinking on my part.